# how can I scale the markers with Plotly.net? (F#/C#)

Tags: f#, plotly

I am drawing markers like this:

```
Chart.Point (points, MarkerSymbol = MarkerSymbol.TriangleUp,   MarkerColor = Color.fromKeyword ColorKeyword.Green)
```

Is there a way to scale them? because right now, on the whole chart, the markers look tiny

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure which markers you want to enlarge, but the first thing that works is to increase the size of the graph. Also, if you want to be interactive, you can use the zoom button in the menu or drag the area you want to enlarge.

Comment: I'm talking about the microscopic little red down arrow; I'm not surprised you didn't see it :D  it's roughly 45% on the x and 20% on the y. the main graph is large and I'm using the live graph, but these markers don't zoom, they remain at a constant size

Comment: I now understand the meaning of marker size. I usually use Plotly in Python, so I'm not sure if this applies to other languages, but wouldn't `marker-size=25` be valid? Here is the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/#custom-marker-symbols) in python

Comment: @r-beginners the api is a bit different in dotnet. There is something called MarkerSizeMode, but it's not the same thing. I'm guessing they need to be wrapped in a 'style' or something like that, but I can't find anything about it

Comment: You may have already checked the F# version of the [reference](https://plotly.com/fsharp/marker-style/) I mentioned earlier, but can you set it by size?`Chart.withMarkerStyle(Size=20,...)`

Comment: yes, that is it! thanks! interestingly plotly.net and plotly.com are two completely different sites and I was on plotly.net; I'm curious what's the difference